# update row value using another table in spark java

Tags: java, sql, database, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 datasets in java spark, first one contains id, name , age
and second one are the same, i need to check values (name and id) and if it's similar update the age with new age in dataset2

i tried all possible ways but i found that java in spark don't have much resourses and all possible ways not worked

this is one i tried :

```
        dataset1.createOrReplaceTempView("updatesTable");
        datase2.createOrReplaceTempView("carsTheftsFinal2");
        updatesNew.show();
          Dataset<Row> test = spark.sql( "ALTER carsTheftsFinal2 set carsTheftsFinal2.age = updatesTable.age from updatesTable where carsTheftsFinal2.id = updatesTable.id AND carsTheftsFinal2.name = updatesTable.name ");
         test.show(12);
```

and this is the error :

> Exception in thread "main"
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:  no viable
> alternative at input 'ALTER carsTheftsFinal2'(line 1, pos 6)

**I have hint: that i can use join to update without using update statement ( java spark not provide update )**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that we have `ds1` with this data:

```
+---+-----------+---+
| id|       name|age|
+---+-----------+---+
|  1|    Someone| 18|
|  2|       Else| 17|
|  3|SomeoneElse| 14|
+---+-----------+---+
```

and `ds2` with this data:

```
+---+----------+---+
| id|      name|age|
+---+----------+---+
|  1|   Someone| 14|
|  2|      Else| 18|
|  3|NotSomeone| 14|
+---+----------+---+
```

According to your expected result, the final table would be:

```
+---+-----------+---+
| id|       name|age|
+---+-----------+---+
|  3|SomeoneElse| 14| <-- not modified, same as ds
|  1|    Someone| 14| <-- modified, was 18
|  2|       Else| 18| <-- modified, was 17
+---+-----------+---+
```

This is achieved with the following transformations, first, we rename `ds2`'s `age` with `age2`.

```
val renamedDs2 = ds2.withColumnRenamed("age", "age2")
```

Then:

```
// we join main dataset with the renamed ds2, now we have age and age2
ds1.join(renamedDs2, Seq("id", "name"), "left")
  // we overwrite age, if age2 is not null from ds2, take it, otherwise leave age
  .withColumn("age", 
    when(col("age2").isNotNull, col("age2")).otherwise(col("age"))
  )
  // finally, we drop age2
  .drop("age2")
```

Hope this does what you want!

Comment: Thanks alot, yes this is what i need, put with sorry i had a problem with `Seq` and `isNotNull` API's `Cannot resolve method 'Seq' ` and `Cannot resolve symbol 'isNotNull'` how can i solve that please ?

Comment: In Java, you can do .isNotNull(), and for the joins, you can do ds1.col("id").equalTo(ds2.col("id")) && ds1.col("name").equalTo(ds2.col("name"))

Please, mark the question as correct if you think this is what you want so other people can reach out easier

Comment: it worked thanks  a lot, but there's small problem, id and name are repeated with id and name headers so if i dropped it main cols will dropped too, only age2 dropped , how can i drop it ?

Comment: If you are doing this in Java, then you will have to rename right table's names (as I did with age), then you can drop id2, name2 and age2.